# Draw graph G with the following properties

Tags: graph-theory

a) every two adjacent vertices lie on a common cycle

b) there exist two adjacent edges that do not lie on a common cycle

Honestly, the wording is confusing me the most. Every two adjacent vertices? What does that even mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that for any two vertices which have an edge between them, there is a cycle containing those two vertices.

You also want a similar property for edges to be **not always** true.

An example is the "bowtie graph": vertices $a,b,c,d,e$ with $c$ adjacent to everything else, $a$ adjacent to $b$ and $d$ adjacent to $e$.

Comment: So would a be K_{3} and b be the bowtie graph?

Comment: Is it two questions?  I thought you meant it was one question.

Comment: i guess i'll assume it is one. thanks anyway